# i am facing a problem while migrating database .. using xampp

Tags: laravel

I don't understand how to fix this problem. what should i do witthon connection.php and connector.php file
In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES   ) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where table_schema = STDHUB and table   _name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 67:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES   )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: do you have correct settings on your .env file?

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that you're using wrong credentials to connect to `MySQL`.

Check your `MySQL` credentials, for example:

```
username: root
password: secret
```

Then you should change the value in your `.env` in your Laravel project folder. If `.env` does not exist, copy a new one from your `.env.example`.

```
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check DB_User , DB_PWD in your .env file